How to sort the JFrog artifact list with "created" date?
I am working on a shell script where I need to fetch artifacts information which are older than 30 days. After that depending upon other conditions some of these artifacts will be deleted.
From Postman app, I tried to test the 'search' API with 'aql' but the results are same even if change sorting order to '$asc' or '$desc' for "created" date. Artifact which was created on '2024-03-22T13:28:15.924Z' comes on the top every time.
Request
Method: POST
URL: https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/search/aql
Headers: 'Accept: application/json' 'Content-Type: text/plain'
Body:
items.find(
    {"repo":"xyz-app-generic-local"},
    {"created":{"$lt":"2024-06-02T14:06:12Z"}}
).include("@jenkins.build.number", "@deployedToDEV", "@deployedToQA", "@deployedToUAT", "@deployedToPROD").sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).distinct(true)

Response:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "repo": "xyz-app-generic-local",
            "path": ".",
            "name": "app_12.zip",
            "type": "file",
            "size": 26616618,
            "created": "2024-03-22T13:28:15.924Z",
            "created_by": "app-jfroguser",
            "modified": "2024-04-24T16:31:17.490Z",
            "modified_by": "app-jfroguser",
            "updated": "2024-04-24T16:31:19.870Z",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "key": "deployedToDEV",
                    "value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "key": "deployedToPROD",
                    "value": "false"
                },
                {
                    "key": "deployedToQA",
                    "value": "false"
                },
                {
                    "key": "jenkins.build.number",
                    "value": "12"
                },
                {
                    "key": "deployedToUAT",
                    "value": "false"
                }
            ]
        },
.
.
.
]
}

